# zod enum and object as const

Tags: typescript, validation, object, types, zod

I have the following object that is autogenerated

```
export const ReportDimensions = {
  CHANNELS: 'CHANNELS',
  DAY: 'DAY',
  DOW: 'DOW',
  MONTH: 'MONTH',
  WEEK: 'WEEK'
} as const;
```

I would like to use zod, and allow only value that are in this object, so like

`["MONTH","WEEK","DOW", "DAY", "CHANNELS"]`

I tried to do

```
z.enum(Object.keys(ReportDimensions))
```

but I get

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(values: readonly [string, ...string[]], params?: RawCreateParams): ZodEnum<[string, ...string[]]>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly [string, ...string[]]'.
> Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(values: [string, ...string[]], params?: RawCreateParams): ZodEnum<[string, ...string[]]>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, ...string[]]'.
> Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.ts(2769)

How can I properly do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Try using `z.nativeEnum(ReportDimensions)`

---

### OR

2. Try changing `const ReportDimensions = { ... } as const` to
   `const ReportDimensions = [ 'CHANNELS', 'DAY', 'DOW', 'MONTH', 'WEEK' ] as const;`.